# How to catch fire of onItemSelected of a Spinner, after the interface has been setup?

Tags: android, events, view, spinner, android-sdk-2.1

I am having an Android view with a Spinner on it.
I call a populateSpinner() method to add some default values to it.

I also have a `onItemSelected()` event which gets called before the view is completed to print.
I would like to run a code inside this block only when the user changes the selected items, not when I add or the form gets created.

How is possible that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried waiting until you have populated the Spinner to register the onItemSelectedListener?

Comment: By 'waiting until you have populated the Spinner', you mean setting the adapter for the spinner, right? I call 'setOnItemSelectedListener' only after I call 'setAdapter' method on the spinner, but still the 'onItemSelected' event gets fired at the initialization of the activity.

Answer (score 2):

Pentium10, I have found a solution for this problem and posted it here (with code sample):

[Spinner onItemSelected() executes when it is not suppose to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624825/spinner-onitemselected-executes-when-it-is-not-suppose-to/5918177#5918177)