# Spinner not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-alertdialog, android-spinner

I am using 3 spinners in Alertdialog. while i am using spinners without onitemselectedlistener it populates correctly and when i am using onItemSelectedListener its not populating the values, And i tried some other suggestions from [stackoverflow Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624825/spinner-onitemselected-executes-when-it-is-not-suppose-to) now its populated first time when i click some item All the values will gone

i posted my alertdialog code here

```
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraDemo.this);
    myDialog.setTitle("Save");
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LinearLayout layout1 = new LinearLayout(CameraDemo.this);
    layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Spinner spin = new Spinner(CameraDemo.this);
    Cursor cursor = placeData.queueAllDoc();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    SimpleCursorAdapter cu = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, new String[]{SQLiteoperations.DOC_TYPE}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    cu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(cu);

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if(mSpinnerInitializedCount < mSpinnerCount){
                mSpinnerInitializedCount++;
                return;                         
            }
            Cursor incursor1 = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int did = incursor1.getInt(incursor1.getColumnIndex(SQLiteoperations.DOC_ID));
            doc_id = did;
            System.out.println(did);
            incursor1.close();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        return;
        }
    });

    LayoutParams TxtLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final EditText saveEdt = new EditText(CameraDemo.this);
    LayoutParams locationEdtLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    saveEdt.setLayoutParams(locationEdtLayoutParams);

    final TextView saveTxt = new TextView(CameraDemo.this);
    saveTxt.setLayoutParams(TxtLayoutParams);
    saveTxt.setText("Name");
    TextView groupTxt = new TextView(CameraDemo.this);
    groupTxt.setLayoutParams(TxtLayoutParams);
    groupTxt.setText("Group");
    TextView clientTxt = new TextView(CameraDemo.this);
    clientTxt.setLayoutParams(TxtLayoutParams);
    clientTxt.setText("Client");
    TextView docTxt = new TextView(CameraDemo.this);
    docTxt.setLayoutParams(TxtLayoutParams);
    docTxt.setText("Document Type");

    TableRow grouprow = new TableRow(CameraDemo.this);
    grouprow.setLayoutParams(rowparams);
    final TableRow clientrow = new TableRow(CameraDemo.this);
    clientrow.setLayoutParams(rowparams);
    final TableRow docrow = new TableRow(CameraDemo.this);
    docrow.setLayoutParams(rowparams);
    final TableRow namerow = new TableRow(CameraDemo.this);
    namerow.setLayoutParams(rowparams);



    Spinner spin2 = new Spinner(CameraDemo.this);
    Cursor cursor2 = placeData.queueAllGroup();
    startManagingCursor(cursor2);
    SimpleCursorAdapter cu2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor2, new String[]{SQLiteoperations.GROUP_NAME}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    cu2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin2.setAdapter(cu2);

    spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if(mSpinnerInitializedCount < mSpinnerCount){
                mSpinnerInitializedCount++;
                return;                         
            }
            Cursor incursor2 = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int gid = incursor2.getInt(incursor2.getColumnIndex(SQLiteoperations.GROUP_ID));
            group_id = gid;
            System.out.println(gid);
            incursor2.close();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            return;
        }
    });

    Spinner spin3 = new Spinner(CameraDemo.this);
    Cursor cursor3 = placeData.queueAllClient(1);
    startManagingCursor(cursor3);
    SimpleCursorAdapter cu3 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor3, new String[]{SQLiteoperations.CLIENT_NAME}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    cu3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin3.setAdapter(cu3);

    spin3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if(mSpinnerInitializedCount < mSpinnerCount){
                mSpinnerInitializedCount++;
                return;                         
            }
            Cursor incursor3 = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int cid = incursor3.getInt(incursor3.getColumnIndex(SQLiteoperations.CLIENT_ID));
            client_id = cid;
            System.out.println(cid);
            incursor3.close();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            return;
        }
    });

    grouprow.addView(groupTxt);
    grouprow.addView(spin2);
    clientrow.addView(clientTxt);
    clientrow.addView(spin3);
    docrow.addView(docTxt);
    docrow.addView(spin);
    namerow.addView(saveTxt);
    namerow.addView(saveEdt);

    layout1.addView(grouprow);
    layout1.addView(clientrow);
    layout1.addView(docrow);
    layout1.addView(namerow);

    myDialog.setView(layout1);
    myDialog.show();
```

pls help me to find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you should close the cursor which you get by calling

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You are not querying anything. It is already managed by Activity

Comment: Remove All cursor.closE calls