# On Spinner init -> automatic selection avoid

Tags: android, spinner

I searched for a solution to avoid the automatic selection on a dynamically created spinner. I found that link: [Spinner onItemSelected() executes when it is not suppose to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624825/spinner-onitemselected-executes-when-it-is-not-suppose-to/5918177#5918177)

But I can't get it work on my code:

```
private void populateSpinner() {
        //Spinner spinnerKostenstellen;
        //spinnerKostenstellen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        //spinnerKostenstellen = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        AlertDialog.Builder adb2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater adbInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View SpinnerLayout = adbInflater2.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
        adb2.setView(SpinnerLayout);
        adb2.setTitle("Kostenstelle auswählen:");
        spinnerKostenstellen = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinnerKostenstellen.setSelection(1, false);
        spinnerKostenstellen.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        //spinnerKostenstellen.setCallbackDuringFling(false);
        List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < kostenstellenList.size(); i++) {
            lables.add(kostenstellenList.get(i).getKst());
        }

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        //ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //ArrayAdapter<String> kostenstellenList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinnerKostenstellen.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        adb2.show();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**(EDIT) below code hide first blank value from the spinner**

```
List<String> urlist = new ArrayList<String>();
urlist.add("");   //  Initial dummy entry
urlist.add("yourstring1");
urlist.add("yourstring2");
urlist.add("yorustring3");


ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, urlist) {
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = null;

        // If this is the initial blnk entry, make it hidden
        if (position == 0) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setHeight(0);
            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v = tv;
        }
        else {
            // Pass convertView as null to prevent reuse of special case views
            v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
        }

        return v;
    }
};

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: The method setSelection(int) in the type AbsSpinner is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: when you get the arraylist of item then insert a blank item at any position by yourself and the in setSelection(yourcustomaddedposition).

Comment: And in adapter you can put the condition like if( (item != null) && ( position == yourcustomaddedposition)) {
        row.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

Comment: i have now added a blank item, but it still automatically selects the blank item and goes on with the code

Comment: I update my code above please , check, hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `OnItemSelectedListener` to be set after the dialog is shown (which is also after the adapter is set).  This should prevent the spinner from firing its listener before the user chooses something.  `YOURCLASSNAME` would be whatever the name of your current class this code lives in.

```
private void populateSpinner() {
    //Spinner spinnerKostenstellen;
    //spinnerKostenstellen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    //spinnerKostenstellen = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    AlertDialog.Builder adb2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View SpinnerLayout = adbInflater2.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
    adb2.setView(SpinnerLayout);
    adb2.setTitle("Kostenstelle auswählen:");
    spinnerKostenstellen = (Spinner) SpinnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinnerKostenstellen.setSelection(1, false);
    //spinnerKostenstellen.setCallbackDuringFling(false);
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < kostenstellenList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(kostenstellenList.get(i).getKst());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    //ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> kostenstellenList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerKostenstellen.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    // use .create to get the AlertDialog 
    AlertDialog dialog =  adb2.create();
    // set an OnShowListener
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            spinnerKostenstellen.setOnItemSelectedListener(YOURCLASSNAME.this);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: doesnt change anything, it still selected automatic

Comment: i didnt changed anything, and now it doesnt work anymore. but i didnt worked on the code :(